# Dual boot between the same linux OS on two different disks?

Tags: linux, boot, debian, multi-boot, grub

I have a computer with two separate hard drives, I want to use one for personal use, and one for work related uses.
Since I am quite used to Debian, I thought I could simply install the first instance with full disk encryption on the first disk, then do the same on the second disk, and have grub propose two different instances of Debian, with maybe a bit of trouble distinguishing the two of them in the grub menu without renaming.

What happened instead is that grub only present me with one Debian instance (the second to be installed), and gParted shows that the first one still looks fine

- Is there a way to "re add" the first Debian instance to the grub menu ?
- Is there something particular with having the partitions on two different physical disks that I forgot ? Or with two instances of the same OS ?
- One of the disk can be removed and readded easily, does the fact I may remove it something I need to be careful about ?

Comment: Take a look at this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335247/two-linux-distributions-grub-does-not-detect-other-one). Note the comment that suggest mount both boot partitions and running `update-grub`. See if any of these suggestions help.